# Load Dataset to SQL script (in powershell)

Tags: sql, powershell, large-data-volumes

I would like to extract a large dataset from an SQL server database on one server and then include that dataset on another database on a different server. As link server is not an option, I have tried a powershell script, and would like something like:

```
$connection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$command = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
... etc for SqlDataAdapter as well
$adapter.Fill($dataset1)

$connection2 = ... (to a database on another server)
$command2 = ...
Load $dataset1 into $command2
$command2.Fill($dataset2)
```

How do I load dataset 1 into command 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you thought about the SQLBulkCopy class?  [Here](http://poshcode.org/2276)'s a powershell function that uses it to push data from one dataset to a different SQL Connection.

Comment: Yes SQLBulkCopy works great. The true challenge are the out of memory exceptions at $adapter.Fill($dataset1) when the table is really large.

Comment: If you pass a datareader, you don't have to pull the records down into a datatable.  The SQLBulkCopy will "stream" them.    In PowerShell, you will probably need to do something like this:
$bulkCopy.WriteToServer($cmd.ExecuteReader())

i.e. don't call the ExecuteReader method earlier because PowerShell likes to unroll datareader objects.

Comment: @Mike Are you sure? I'm playing with a tables of 400425 rows and can't see a difference between both modes of invoking ExecuteReader. Using datatable each third trial had an out of memory exception.

Comment: I've copied multi-million row tables with no memory issues (using my laptop).

Comment: @Mike When PowerShell unrolls the Data Reader, than I must see a difference using ps before and after $reader = $commandSourceData.ExecuteReader(). See the edit of my code. I get no diofference.

Comment: I must have been dreaming when I did it the first time (it was months ago).  I've recreated it without my changes and it didn't do much different in terms of memory.

Comment: the page linked no longer has that code and this answer is no longer viable nor useful

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure, that you want to have the whole dataset in memory ?

If you just want to copy the result of a query to another table better use data reader to avoid out of memory exceptions.

```
# cf. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx

$SourceConnectionString      = "Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=source_db;Integrated Security=True"
$DestinationConnectionString = "Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=Destination_db;Integrated Security=True"

$tableName = "MyTable"
$sql = "select * FROM $tableName"

$sourceConnection  = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SQLConnection($ConnectionString)
$sourceConnection.open()
$commandSourceData  = New-Object system.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand($sql,$sourceConnection)
#$commandSourceData .CommandTimeout = '300'

ps 'powershell_ise'
$reader = $commandSourceData.ExecuteReader()
ps 'powershell_ise'


try
{
    $bulkCopy = new-object ("Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy") $DestinationConnectionString
    $bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = $tableName
    $bulkCopy.BatchSize = 5000
    $bulkCopy.BulkCopyTimeout = 0
    $bulkCopy.WriteToServer($reader)
}
catch
{
    $ex = $_.Exception
    Write-Host "Write-DataTable$($connectionName):$ex.Message"
}
finally
{
    $reader.close()
}
```

**Edit:**

After reading Mikes comment, that PowerShell possibly unrolls the datareader object, I retried my code replacing.

```
$sql = "select * FROM $tableName"
```

by

```
$sql = "select * FROM $tableName union all select * FROM $tableName union all select * FROM $tableName union all select * FROM $tableName union all select * FROM $tableName "
```

It still worked and I had no out of memory exception in

```
$reader = $commandSourceData.ExecuteReader()
```

Until I observe problems, I have no reason to try Mikes variation.

**2nd Edit:**

I modified the code by adding

```
ps 'powershell_ise'
```

before and after

```
$reader = $commandSourceData.ExecuteReader()
```

I do not observe any changesin memory usage and therefore I conclude that Mikes assumption about PowerShell unrolling the datareader object doesn't apply.